# What is this tiny blue flower in my garden?

Tags: identification, flowers

I don't remember what seeds I have planted there but I notice a blue flower growing out and I don't know what the plant name is. The plant is small and so is the flower. This plant grows in North Carolina.

Here is the picture:
[image: Blue flower]

Comment: The plant immediately to the right and slightly above the blue flowered plant is a tomato!

Comment: Yeah, I have A lot of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a cynoglossum, probably *[Cynoglossum amabile](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/cynoglossum-amabile/)* (Chinese Forget-me-not). There is also a species native to North Carolina (*[Cynoglossum virginianum](https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/flower/wild-comfrey)*). The native wildflower would make more sense for the ID, but that species has flowers that are a lighter blue, and its leaves are wider at the base. Note that the pictured flower could be a cultivar of either species.

There are other, similar, possibilities, but the corolla-like structure in the center of the flower is pretty indicative of Cynoglossum.