# What is this plant that is growing in my garden

Tags: identification

I have a plant in my garden that is pretty similar to [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/59558/what-is-this-tiny-blue-flower-in-my-garden), and I'm not sure what it is. It is about half a foot. It is growing in North Carolina, United States in tilled soil.

Picture:
[image: Unknown plant]

Comment: it looks a lot like coca, but somehow i doubt that's right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost certainly a coreopsis, and is probably Lanceleaf Coreopsis (*Coreopsis lanceolata*). It's native to much of the US, including North Carolina. Here's a photo of two growing in my garden. The smaller plant on the left is a seedling of the larger plant on the right:
[image]
Keys for identification are the leaf shape, leaf substance (thick and semi-glossy), and the odd and occasional notches in some of the leaves. C. lanceolata gets about two feet tall and wide and can become weedy if allowed to go to seed.

There are other related coreopsis such as *Coreopsis tripteris* and *Coreopsis palmata*, but their leaves are different. The one in your garden is probably a first-year seedling and will bloom next year.